# python script instantiate GameObject on Unity photon network

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, photon

I want to have a python (or something that can run in the Raspberry Pi console and also interact with MySQL) script running on my Raspberry Pi to instantiate a game object on my unity photon networked game, this is so people can send maps via a text file which my code can interperate and then the script will spawn all the gameObjects named in the file at the cords set and then the players are spawned in.
 I know how to do all the other stuff on Raspberry Pi without an actual Unity game open on it to do that, I just need some way to make the python script spawn the gameobjects in before the players join. Thx - Billy.

The code is currently in C# which runs in an actual Unity game that can spawn stuff in, the code which does this looks like this:

```
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileMapDIR);
    string s = reader.ReadLine();

    TerrainType = float.Parse(s);
    if(TerrainType == 1){
        GameObject myTerrainGO = (GameObject)PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Terrain1", Terrain1Pos, Quaternion.identity, 0);
    }
    if(TerrainType == 2){
        GameObject myTerrainGO = (GameObject)PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Terrain2", Terrain1Pos, Quaternion.identity, 0);
    }
    if(TerrainType == 3){
        GameObject myTerrainGO = (GameObject)PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Terrain3", Terrain1Pos, Quaternion.identity, 0);
    }

    s = reader.ReadLine();

    while(s != null){

        char[] delimiter = {':'};
        string[] feilds = s.Split(delimiter);
        string objName = feilds[0];
        float lx = float.Parse(feilds[1]);
        float ly = float.Parse(feilds[2]);
        float lz = float.Parse(feilds[3]);
        float ra1 = float.Parse(feilds[4]);
        Vector3 positionA = new Vector3(lx, ly, lz);

        GameObject myCrateGO = (GameObject)PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(objName, positionA, Quaternion.Euler(0, ra1, 0), 0);

        s = reader.ReadLine();
    }

    ingame = true;
```